# Why was Rapunzel with long hair?

Tags: character, tangled, ralph-breaks-the-internet

According to this [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84211/did-rapunzels-hair-get-the-power-back) about *Tangled*, Rapunzel couldn't get her hair back. Then why is she shown with long hair in *Ralph Breaks the Internet*?

[image]

Comment: but answer on same question say she got her hair back with different power

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because all of the *Tangled* merchandise uses Rapunzel with long hair. So the Princesses are depicted with their common look and standard costume, the actual movie plots have no bearing on their appearance in *Ralph Breaks the Internet*.

Comment: That's gonna require a source to back that up.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths 
Isn't that logical?

Answer (score 5):

In the *Tangled* TV series, Rapunzel gets her hair back:

Since the movie also contains a reference to Cassandra from the show, it would appear that the movie takes place including TV canon.

This reference, by the way, is a painting of an owl on the wall during the princesses scene that looks quite similar to Cassandra's owl from the TV series.

[image: screenshot of YouTube video comparing the painted owl to the owl in the TV series]

(Hat tip to [Flicks and the City](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_wLjYQVzWE), at around 4:40.)

Also, of course, because she wouldn't be recognizable without her distinctive hair.

Comment: Well, these TV series do not count as official.

Comment: What do you mean, they're not official? They're officially produced by Disney. I don't see why they wouldn't be "official".

Comment: I'm sure that the money Disney gets from the Tangled series is official money and not play money.

Comment: "_...looks quite similar to Cassandra's owl_" - Really? Other than both being owls I wouldn't say they look anything alike!